# what is the difference between setting date condition with extract date and date between d1 and d2 in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date

i have written two queries which i expected would give me the same data.

Query 1

```
select transaction, count(*)
from table
where create_date between to_Date('02/11/2017','MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('02/17/2017','MM/DD/YYYY')
group by transaction
```

Query 2

```
select transaction, count(*)
from table
where extract(day from create_date) between 11 and 17
and extract(month from create_date)=2
and extract(year from create_date)=2017
group by transaction
```

Results from query 1

```
Transaction1 1155
Transaction2 333
Transaction3 5188
```

Results from query 2

```
Transaction1 1422
Transaction2 415
Transaction3 6155
```

why am i getting different results?

Comment: Does `create_date` include a time component? Because if so, I'd expect your first query to exclude any rows which happened *after* midnight at the *start* of the 17th. (Which is the value your `to_date` call has created as the end point)

Comment: the datatype for create_date is Date

Comment: Yes, but in Oracle, [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT413) is a misnomer since it can also store hours, minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first query gets the values where the values are between `2017-02-11 00:00:00` and `2017-02-17 00:00:00`.

The second query gets the values where the values are between `2017-02-11 00:00:00` and `2017-02-17 23:59:59`.

So, if there are values between `2017-02-17 00:00:01` and `2017-02-17 23:59:59` then they will be included in the `COUNT` of the second query but not the first.

Try:

```
select transaction, count(*)
from   table
where  create_date >= DATE '2017-02-11'
AND    create_date <  DATE '2017-02-18'
group by transaction
```

or

```
select transaction, count(*)
from   table
where  TRUNC( create_date ) BETWEEN DATE '2017-02-11' AND DATE '2017-02-18'
group by transaction
```

*(Note: the later query will not use indexes on `create_date` and would need a function-based index on `TRUNC( create_date )` instead.)*

Comment: why would the time affect the result, the data type for create_date is Date.

Comment: @VenkateshwaranVenky In Oracle, a date data type is stored internally as [7-bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/2087/dates/6848/the-format-of-a-date) (2 for year, 1 each for month, day, hour, minute and second) and **always** has a time component. If you use `TO_DATE( '02/11/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY' )` then the time component will be `00:00:00` but if you use something like `SYSDATE` then it will have the current date and time.

Comment: @VenkateshwaranVenky also note, Oracle does not have a `DATETIME` data type - it only has `DATE` (date and time) and `TIMESTAMP` (date, time and fractional seconds with optional timezone).

Answer (score 0):

TO_DATE - Convert String to Datetime, and internally the between clause is working on HH: MI: SS in your first query , for making same result from second one need to take care about the HH: MI: SS in your second query

Comment: There is no such thing as a `DATETIME` data type in Oracle - there is only `DATE` (years - seconds) or `TIMESTAMP` (year - fractional seconds).